# How to iterate through json response

Tags: json, groovy

I require a little guidance on trying to find a list of values from a JSON response.

I have a JSON that looks like this below:

```
"reviewRatingCount":    [
            {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "xxx",
         "value": x,
         "percentage": 8.49
      },
            {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "xxx",
         "value": x,
         "percentage": 11.19
      },
            {
         "id": 3,
         "name": "xxx",
         "value": x,
         "percentage": 22.74
      }
...
```

Now I have performed a check to ensure 'ReviewRatingCount' does not equal null:

```
def reviewratingcount = json.reviewratingcount
assert reviewratingcount != null
```

What I want to do is ensure that the ids within this 'reviewRatingCount' equals 1, 2, 3. So virtually i want it to iterate through the ids within the reviewRatingCount and ensure all the ids contain the correct values. How is this applied in groovy scripting so then I can apply it to not only this example, but also for the other checks like 'name'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to iterate, use `*` operator:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{"reviewRatingCount":    [
            {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "Terrible",
         "value": 214,
         "percentage": 8.49
      },
            {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "Poor",
         "value": 282,
         "percentage": 11.19
      },
            {
         "id": 3,
         "name": "Average",
         "value": 573,
         "percentage": 22.74
      }
]}'''

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
assert slurped.reviewRatingCount*.id == [1, 2, 3]
```